# Any official MongoDb session state provider available for C# .NET

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am just looking for session state provider for .net with MongoDb, actually i do not find any official Nuget packages, or better reliable production quality one.

Please advice if we have any existing solutions for the same, or suggest any alternate solution to approach on

Thanks in advance

Comment: No, there's not an official 10gen written provider. There is at least one open source provider that you've likely seen.

Answer (score 0):

This is about the most popular one and should suit your needs.

Github project: https://github.com/freshlogic/MongoDB.Web

Nuget package: http://www.nuget.org/packages/MongoDB.Web